# VBA Change Line Color of Chart with ColorIndex

Tags: excel, vba, colors, line, excel-charts

The code below works and sets the color of the four lines with the three values for rgb. The three rgb values are filled in an array (*Clr*) which is not very clear. Is there an alternative way for instant by using *Hex* numbers, *ColorIndex* or the predefined colors like *vbBlack*?

```
Sub CreateChart()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Clr() As Variant

'Clr = Array("vbBlack", "vbBlue", "vbRed", "vbCyan", "vbGreen", "vbMagenta")    ' colors as types
'Clr = Array("&H0", "&HFF0000", "&Hff", "&HFFFF00", "&HFF00", "&HFF00FF")       ' Hex of colors as String
'Clr = Array(&H0, &HFF0000, &HFF, &HFFFF00, &HFF00, &HFF00FF)                   ' Hex Values of colors
'Clr = Array(&H0, &HFF0000, &HFF, &HFFFF00, &HFF00, &HFF00FF)                   ' IndexColor
Clr = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255)
With Charts.Add
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Plot").Range("A12:E213")
    j = 0
    For i = 2 To 5
        With .FullSeriesCollection(i - 1).Format.Line
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(Clr(j), Clr(j + 1), Clr(j + 2))
            j = j + 3
        End With
    Next
End With
   
End Sub
```

Comment: ColorIndex is from an old color system in Excel 97-2003. It's still available, but is mostly not very useful, since now colors can be specified directly using RGB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your code works well, just get rid of quotation marks and `RGB` function. Also there's nothing wrong with hex values, they work fine.

```
Sub CreateChart()
Dim Color As Variant
Dim Source as Range
Dim i As Long

    Set Source = Sheets("Plot").Range("A12:E213")
    Color = Array(vbBlack, vbBlue, vbRed, vbCyan, vbGreen, vbMagenta)
    ' Array(&H0, &HFF0000, &HFF, &HFFFF00, &HFF00, &HFF00FF) works as well
    With Charts.Add
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        .SetSourceData Source
        For i = 1 To .FullSeriesCollection.Count
            .FullSeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = Color(i - 1)
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

To use `Color(i)` instead of somewhat clumsy `Color(i - 1)` we should add `Option Base 1` to start `Array` index from one by default. But it's up to you, of course.

P.S. Take a look at [xlRGBColor enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.XlRgbColor)

Comment: Thank you, it works! I didn't know about the xlRGBColor enumeration! This is really a great color collection.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Hex2Dec()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.hex2dec) WorkSheetFunction ?

```
Sub CreateChart()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Clr() As Variant

    'Clr = Array("vbBlack", "vbBlue", "vbRed", "vbCyan", "vbGreen", "vbMagenta")    ' colors as types
    'Clr = Array("&H0", "&HFF0000", "&Hff", "&HFFFF00", "&HFF00", "&HFF00FF")       ' Hex of colors as String
    Clr = Array(&H0, &HFF0000, &HFF, &HFFFF00, &HFF00, &HFF00FF)                   ' Hex Values of colors
    'Clr = Array(&H0, &HFF0000, &HFF, &HFFFF00, &HFF00, &HFF00FF)                   ' IndexColor
    'Clr = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255)
    With Charts.Add
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Plot").Range("A12:E213")
        j = 0
        For i = 2 To 5
            With .FullSeriesCollection(i - 1).Format.Line
                .ForeColor.RGB = WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(Clr(j))
                j = j + 1
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```